# The style attribute is overriding the css property assigned with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am having a problem in animating the navbar.

Please find the code above. 
It works well when i scroll down, but when i come back up, the css value is not getting assigned as specified in the javascript.
Please help me in this regard.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
.positioned {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 15px;
  width:100%;
}
.content{
  height:1200px;
}



/* Just cosmetic stuff */

body {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    height:1200px;
}

div {
    background: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    padding: 5px;
}

.positioned {
    background: #e1eef5;
}
</style>
<div class="navbar">
</div>

<div class="positioned">
    position: fixed; bottom: 10px; left: 15px;
</div>

<div class="content">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 250) {
        $('.positioned').animate({
          backgroundColor: "red",
          height: '300px'},1000);
    } else { 
        $('#box').css('display', 'block');
        $('.positioned').css("background-color", "yellow");
        // var rowNavbar = $('.row-navbar');
        // $('.row-navbar').animate({
        //   height: '130px'},1000);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Here's the link:
http://codepen.io/mohanjp20/pen/QKjOOz

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself, and not just in a link.

Comment: Please construct a minimal test case and embed it in your question. You will get more attention if the code is visible in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If more than one animation method(the number of times you scroll) is called on the same element, the later animations are placed in the effects queue for the element. These animations will not begin until the first one completes. When .stop() is called, the next animation in the queue begins immediately

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 250) {
    $('.positioned').stop().animate({
      backgroundColor: "red",
      height: '300px'},1000);
} else { 
   $('.positioned').stop().animate({
     display:'block',
      backgroundColor: "yellow"
      },1000);
}
});
```